# JAVA Regex identifying strings \"string"\ or characters \'char'\ inside a string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, char

So, I am facing the following issue:

The strings that I am getting are in the form of "string" or 'char'. In short they are coming with their own '' and "".  When the String variable in my code stores them in itself they look something like this "\"string\"" and "\'char\'".

(I am also getting a lot of values with different formats for example hexa-decimals, octa and int. I am using java regex to identify them and I am successful in doing so. The only problem is with string and char values.)

I want to use java regex to differentiate between them and get the value of the char and string without all the "" and ''.

Following is the pattern I am using to identify char, but it does not seem to work.

Pattern charPattern = Pattern.compile("\s*[\'][\S\s][\']\s*");

Pattern charPattern2 = Pattern.compile("\s*['][\S\s][']\s*");

What I am expecting is that the pattern will be able to identify a character 'char'\ of this nature. Afterwards I can just replace the \' with blank to get the main value.

Can some one kindly help.

Comment: In Java `\"` quotes a character inside the string.  There aren't any actual \ in your string unless the string literal contains `"\\"`  The string `"\"string\""` is just `"string"`.  Try printing out the strings to see them.  Show us complete code if you need more help.

Comment: I am basically reading from a C/C++ file. The variables can have int, hexa, octa, char and String etc values. So I am getting "string" and 'char' as input (as they are in C/C++).
When I print my Java String containing these values, the result is "string" or 'char' (with the quotation marks).

Comment: I doubt a regular expression will be sufficient for parsing C strings.  That said, in a regular expression `[\S\s]` is the same as `.`.  More important, however, is that you are passing string to Pattern.compile which has no backslash characters in it.  `'\\'` is a char value that represents *one character.*  `"\\"` is a Java string of length 1.  `"\\s"` is a string of length 2, and which is also a regex that matches one whitespace character.  Hopefully you can extrapolate from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... When the String variable in my code stores them in itself they look something like this "\"string\"" and "\'char\'". ...*
>
> *... I want to use java regex to differentiate between them and get the value of the char and string without all the "" and ''. ...*

You can utilize the *look-around* syntax to assert these values.

This will produce overlapping values.
For example in the text, `"abc" + x + "123"`, the `" + x + "` will be captured.

```
((?<=\").+?(?=\")|(?<=').+?(?='))
```

Here is an example using the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* class.

```java
String s = "123 \"abc\" 456 def '7'89";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?<=\").+?(?=\")|(?<=').+?(?='))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output

```
abc
7
```

Alternately, capture the quotation marks, eliminating the overlapping values, and remove the datum programmatically.

```
(\".+?\"|'.+?')
```

```java
String s = "123 \"abc\" 456 def '7'89", g;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\".+?\"|'.+?')");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    g = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(g.substring(1, g.length() - 1));
}
```